# Invoke-WebRequest, GET with parameters throws exception

Tags: c#, powershell

Need to invoke the following url from PowerShell script:

```
$webAPIUrl =  "http://hostName:portNumber/test/schedule-process/22/true"
```

While invoking exception thrown as "An error has occurred."
PowerShell script:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $webAPIUrl -Method get -UseBasicParsing
```

Same exception was thrown while checking this url with Postman.

C# API code:

```
  public class ScheduleController : ApiController  
  {  
      [HttpGet]  
      public void SchedulingProcess(int scheduleId, bool isScheduleStart)  
      {  

      }  
  }
```

Route configuration code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("SchedulingProcess","test/schedule-process/{scheduleId}/{isScheduleStart}",new { controller = "Schedule", action = "SchedulingProcess" });
```

Working fine while calling from C#:

```
string webAPIUrl = "http://hostName:portNumber/test/schedule-process/22/true";
new WebClient().OpenReadAsync(new Uri(webAPIUrl));
```

Please help me to invoke this url from PowerShell script.

Comment: What version of WebApi are you using? Your route should just need to be defined on the `HttpGet` attribute like:
`[HttpGet("/test/schedule-process/{scheduleId}/{isScheduleStart}")]` instead of being added to the routes manually like that

Comment: Plase try running `try{Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $webAPIUrl -Method get -UseBasicParsing}catch{$_.errordetails.message}` and post what is says, if anything.

Comment: Do you have any more info describing the exception thrown?  How is your site secured / have you tried including the `-UseDefaultCredentials` switch?

Comment: Also consider disabling the custom errors to allow the server to put into the wire what the problem is when invoking from client outside the server. e.g. [Link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1267844.aspx?Web+Config+customErrors+mode+Off+)

Comment: This question is now very outdated.

Answer (score -1):

The Url is invalid. "http://hostName:portNumber/test/schedule-process/22/true". Please use a valid URL.

Comment: No, this is [valid URL format](http://www.usefulutilities.com/support/cfg/dhu.html). Unless it's not what you're tlaking about? Please explain your answer.